# How do I pass an array of integers in a form as a param in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

Let's say I have a collection of schoolrooms, each with an attribute of `class_size`. I have a search form that allows the user to select from a drop-down different ranges of class sizes to filter by.

My scope in the `SchoolRoom` model:

```
scope :by_class_size, -> (low, high) { where(class_size: low..high) }
```

The scope that I tried accepts two params for the range. I want to create form select_tag that allows sending of two parameters, offering the user different ranges such as: (0-25, 25-50, 50+).

I also tried:

```
scope :by_class_size, -> (range) { where(class_size: range) }

# and

scope :by_class_size, -> (*range) { where(class_size:range.first..range.last) }
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
<%= select_tag :class_size, options_for_select([['0-25', [0, 25]], ['25-75', [25, 75]], [['75-150'], [75,150]], ['150+', [150, Float::INFINITY]]]) %>
```

The resulting query in Rails console looks like:

```
SchoolRoom Load (18.4ms)  SELECT  schoolrooms.* FROM schoolrooms  WHERE schoolrooms.class_size BETWEEN 0 AND 0)
```

tl;dr - What's the railsy way to pass a range of numbers (or two param) as a params value in a select_tag?

Comment: can you add the code where you are using params to make query